# Difference in storage of integer values and float values

Tags: types

Integer and Float use 4 bytes of memory for storage. However the range of integer and float are different. How are they stored internally in memory?

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind? Different implementations have different ints and floats, although most of them are similar.

Comment: It does not really matter which language. Take for example c++ and assume that both int and float have 4 bytes then how are they stored so that the ranges are different.

Comment: It... does matter. But Gabriel answered your question, I hope. `:]`

Comment: Floating point representation is usually dictated by the processor architecture, rather than the language being used.  The IEEE-754 standard is the floating point representation you're most likely to encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this about floating point numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point
and this about integers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement